# Is it possible to rescue someone after he/she has been swallowed by Sarlacc?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

[Sarlacc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sarlacc) digests its food in thousands years. And, during this period the victim is kept alive.

Is it possible to rescue a victim who has been swallowed by Sarlacc? Has it been happened possibly in EU?

Comment: If it takes thousands of years to digest you, it's being slow about it, in other words not much immediate damage.

Comment: Wait, how exactly does it keep you alive for thousands of years?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Though no one in recorded history had ever escaped from the Sarlacc, Fett was able to escape, although not entirely unscathed.
>
> <sub>Wookieepedia on [Bobba Fett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett)</sub>

Comment: I would assume he was partially protected by his suit. Another person, unprotected, might have sustained too serious of injuries to survive

Comment: I think it was due to that he was too badass to be eaten by overgrown desert plant:)

Comment: As I recall from the book where it happened, he blasted his way out of the Sarlacc's belly

Comment: The Sarlacc probably has various paralysing venoms to subdue victims and begin the digestive process. It might not be possible to heal someone even if they were rescued. Of course Boba Fett was protected by his Mandalorian Armor which allowed him to use his weapons.

Comment: In the stories in Tales from the Bounty Hunters, it is mentioned that Fett suffers lifelong genetic damage from his short time in the Sarlacc's belly.